# Snow Biome in Dungeon

Tags: terraria

I am trying to farm both Ectoplasm and Frozen Key Mold in Terraria.

If I place more than 300 blocks of ice/snow in the dungeon so that the background turn into ice, will killing dungeon mobs give me the Frozen Key Mold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the wording on the [Biome Key Mold](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Key_mold) wiki page is accurate, I believe the answer to your question is yes. From said page (emphasis is mine):

> After the Wall of Flesh is defeated, **every enemy** has a 0.04% (1 in 2500) chance of dropping a Biome Key Mold. **The type of Biome Key Mold that is dropped depends on the biome you are currently in** (Jungle, Corruption, Crimson, Hallow or Snow). Any mold can drop in Ocean biomes.

Creating an artificial snow biome should eventually yield a frozen key mold, assuming that your character remains within that biome. You'd need to make the biome big enough to ensure that you don't accidentally exit it and enter back into the natural dungeon.

Comment: Confirmed: I got a frozen key mold in my dungeon, which has been filled with ice + snow so that the non-dungeon background turns to ice, and snow biome mobs sometimes spawn.

Comment: Three links to my Key mold farm... http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=459557915  and  http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=459558500  and  http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=459557915  Just place blocks in the upper areas to create your favorite biome influences, you can get jungle, ice, and either normal, crimson or corrupt simultaneously.  If you keep both corrupt and crimson on the lower level, you can just remove a block or two to let the other one take over influence.  Use some pygmy help and block the door to make it fully AFK.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to farm the frozen key mold is to build enough Meteorite blocks in the ice biome, so that the little Meteorites spawn. Add a Water Candle to increase the spawning rates. Get the items that have AFK damage (end-game armors sometimes have a guardian or turret ability) and let it go to work.

For the dungeon, my best way to get ectoplasm was just to keep running through and kill everything. Stay in areas with water candles or place them yourself.

Comment: As of 1.2.3 Meteor heads no longer drop loot in hardmode, including key molds.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question in the OP, either.